# How to perform calculation on AngularJS with Percentage value

Tags: angularjs

Can you help me in doing calculation on AngularJS during data binding?
There is one more issue here, as the discount value is not numeric. It's a string with '%' appended.

**My current output:**

```
Actual: 1000
Discount: 10%
Price after discount : 10%     [I want the calculation here. 1000-(.1*1000) ie 900]

Actual: 600
Discount: 5%
Price after discount : 5%   [I want the calculation here]
```

***index.html***

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ItemCtrl">
    <span ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div>Actual: {{item.actual}}</div> 
      <div>Discount: {{item.discount}}</div> 
       <div>Price after discount : {{item.discount}}</div> 
       <hr>  
        </span>
  </div>
```

***app.js***

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('ItemCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    "discount": "10%",
    "actual": "1000"
  }, {
    "discount": "5%",
    "actual": "600"
  }];
}]);
```

Here's my jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/960bhxab/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to keep the logic out of the dom.

http://jsfiddle.net/errvald/960bhxab/4/

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('ItemCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    "discount": "10%",
    "actual": "1000"
  }, {
    "discount": "5%",
    "actual": "600"
  }];
  
  $scope.items.forEach(function(item){
    item['price'] = item.actual - (item.actual*item.discount.slice(0, -1))/100;
  });
  
}]);
```

```css
.rating {
  color: #a9a9a9;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.rating {
  display: inline-block;
}

.rating li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rating .filled {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ItemCtrl">
    <span ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div>Actual: {{item.actual}}</div> 
      <div>Discount: {{item.discount}}</div> 
       <div>Price after discount : {{item.price}}</div> 
       <hr>  
        </span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you Erevald.. Much cleaner approach. Accepting this for the extra effort to clean code. Only one correction would be ` item['price'] = item.actual*(100-item.discount.slice(0, -1))/100;` so that it would pass for all data scenarios like [ {actual : 1199 , discount: 33%}]. to get output as 803.33 instead of  803.3299999999999

Comment: One question  When I try the `$scope.items.forEach(function(item)` in my local , it complains with an error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:63342/coolapp/app.js:8:17)
    at Object.invoke (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:41:376)'

Comment: @spiderman are the items coming from a service? You can try and do the loop logic before the array is added to a scope and check if `items` is not `undefined`.

Comment: items were coming from $http response. `$scope.items = response.data.items`  .. something like `$http.get("http://myrestapi/items").then(function(response) {
            $scope.items = response.data.items;
        });`

Comment: Ok, try do the loop on the `response.data.items`, and make sure the response is always an array.

Answer (score 1):

If you can remove the % sign from your data, it'll make the math a bit  easier?

```
<div>Price after discount : {{item.actual - item.actual/100*item.discount}}</div>
```

Comment: Pretty similar to what you posted :)

Comment: Thank you :) +1, but both of our calculation logic is not good in displaying price, What Mikkel posted is better when tested with values of {actual : 1199 , discount: 33}. we both get value of '803.3299999999999' but Mikkel's code returns '803.33'

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple. Move the % out of the variable, so it's just for display, then the calculation is easy:

```
   <div>Discount: {{item.discount}}%</div> 
   <div>Price after discount : {{item.actual*(100-item.discount)/100}}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ao17ft09/

Comment: Thank you Mikkel. Your calculation logic is better than mine. Regarding the  '%', it is part of JSON response. I am now replacing using `replace()`

Answer (score 0):

I found myself

Heres the JSFiddle . Please let me know if there's a better approach.

http://jsfiddle.net/960bhxab/2/

***index.html:***

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ItemCtrl">
    <span ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div>Actual: {{item.actual}}</div> 
      <div>Discount: {{item.discount}}</div> 
       <div>Price after discount : {{item.actual-(item.actual*item.discount.replace('%', '')/100)}}</div> 
       <hr>  
        </span>
  </div>
</body>
```